# Typeahead Fill Text Box when Keyup or Keydown event

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am trying to add value from the suggested list of typeahead field(`.typeahead`) to another text input. For example, when I type "A" and do keyup or keydown from the suggestion values, the value to should be shown in the text field `.result` How to achive this in typeahead. Is there any particular method I can hook with?

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead box"/>
<input type="text" class="result" placeholder="Result"/>
<script>
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

var states = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  local: states
});

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: states
});

</script>
```

Comment: Still confused why so many people try to get any good out of typeahead.js. It is a abandoned project, not maintained, 250 open issues - some of them very, very serious - but questions about this mess never seems to end on stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out myself. Use `typeahead:cursorchange` to get the values.

```
$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:cursorchange ', function(ev, suggestion) {
  $('.result').val(suggestion); 
});
```